# Class is applied but not automatically updated on the HTML page

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to apply a green background to an input box when a form is submitted. The code checks if the letter in the input field is the correct letter and turns the input box green if it is. However, the colour only updates when I type in the correct letter *after* I pressed the submit button. I want it to turn green *when* I press submit (not *after*). I've checked the elements in the console and the class green-tile is successfully applied however is it not updating the HTML page. Here is my code:

```
export const compareLetters = (newWord, correctWord, inputArray) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < newWord.length; i++) {
    if(newWord[i] === correctWord[i]) {
      console.log(inputArray);
      inputArray[i].classList.add("green-tile");
      console.log(inputArray[i]);
    } else {
      console.log("This letter does not belong here");
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");
submitButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => newWord(event));

const inputElements = [
    document.getElementById("first-row-first-letter"),
    document.getElementById("first-row-second-letter"),
    document.getElementById("first-row-third-letter"),
    document.getElementById("first-row-fourth-letter"),
    document.getElementById("first-row-fifth-letter")
]

const words = ["hello", "windy", "ghost"]

const compareLetters = (newWord, correctWord, inputArray) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < newWord.length; i++) {
        // console.log(newWord);
        // console.log(correctWord);
        if(newWord[i] === correctWord[i]) {
            console.log(inputArray);
            inputArray[i].classList.add("green-tile");
            console.log(inputArray[i]);
        } else {
            console.log("This letter does not belong here");
        }
    }
}


const newWord = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get each letter from the box and then concatenate them to form the word
    const firstLetter = inputElements[0].value;
    const secondLetter = inputElements[1].value;
    const thirdLetter = inputElements[2].value;
    const fourthLetter = inputElements[3].value;
    const fifthLetter = inputElements[4].value;
    
    const wordGuess = firstLetter + secondLetter + thirdLetter + fourthLetter + fifthLetter;
    console.log(wordGuess);
    compareLetters(wordGuess, words[0], inputElements);
};
```

```css
:root {
    --large-font: 2rem;
    --small-font: 1.15rem;
}

/* Set font and remove default padding and margins */
* {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* center text and input fields */
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

/* styling each input box for character input */
.letter {
    font-size: var(--large-font);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    border: 0.15rem solid rgb(201, 201, 201);
}

/* Center the submit button using flexbox */
.center-button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 4rem;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;;
}

.title {
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

.first-row {
    padding-top: 2.5rem;
}

button {
    border: none;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: var(--small-font);
    border-radius: 15%;
}

.green-tile {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css" />
    <title>Wordle Challenge</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="title center">Wordle</h1>
    <form class="center first-row">
        <input type="text" id="first-row-first-letter" name="first-row-first-letter" class="letter center"/>
        <input type="text" id="first-row-second-letter" name="first-row-second-letter" class="letter center"/>
        <input type="text" id="first-row-third-letter" name="first-row-third-letter" class="letter center"/>
        <input type="text" id="first-row-fourth-letter" name="first-row-fourth-letter" class="letter center"/>
        <input type="text" id="first-row-fifth-letter" name="first-row-fifth-letter" class="letter center"/>
        <div class="center-button">
          <button type="submit" id="submit-button">ENTER</button>  
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="module" src="scripts/main.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: Please show us how your form or submit button uses this function.

Comment: @James I added the code snippet - hope this makes some sense!

Comment: You are comparing only the first word. That's why you get green only for the first one. I don't understand what you are trying to do. Are you going to check the letters only for one word?

Comment: When I type in hello and click the ENTER button the squares go green almost immediately.  Although it happens after clicking the button, it's almost instant.  What are you hoping for?

Comment: @MaziarRumiani I am trying to compare only the first word. Just like playing Wordle

Comment: @James I tried it via the code snippet. It seemed to work but only one. I couldn't replicate it and it is not working with live server or opening the index.html file in my browser. My code has different modules - I wonder if this could affect anything.

Comment: @peterSeliger Thank you for directing me to that post. That post seemed to talk about how to alert the user that their solution was right. However my one is slightly different in that the background colour does not change to green even though the class .green-tile is applied and updating in the DOM

Comment: I don't think the class is added to the dom(It was added only for the first word and since you were not resetting the state you were seeing the `green-tile` class again for the next word). Remember to remove the class at the beginning of your function to avoid this confusion:       `inputArray[i].classList.remove("green-tile");`

Comment: @MaziarRumiani I tried this and it didn't work either. The code is comparing each letter of the `newWord` with `correctWord`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by temporarily setting `inputArray.value` to an empty string then replacing it with the correct letter from `correctWord[i]`. This seems to refresh the DOM somehow and the `green-tile` class is applied and updated in the HTML page.

```
        inputArray[i].classList.add("green-tile");
        inputArray[i].value = "";
        inputArray[i].value = correctWord[i];
```